# What's the name of this font or any other that looks alike?

Tags: font-identification

Due to the gradients and effects on the font I can't use any service like WhatTheFont or WhatFontIs. Any font that looks alike is welcome. Thank you in advance ;)
[image]

*Note: Sorry for the black boxes, apparently the text was NSFW*

Comment: You could select the letters, separate them and fill the selections and then search what the font.

Comment: I've tried to, and haven't found it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be probably [CREAMPUFF](http://www.1001freefonts.com/creampuff.font) font:

[image]